# Solving an inequality involving the absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

I want to find the $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}\right| > \frac{1}{2}$. My current approach looks like this:
$$\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}\right|> \frac{1}{2} \\
\Leftrightarrow x^2 > \frac{1}{2}|x^2-1| \\
\Leftrightarrow x^2 > \frac{1}{2}|x + 1||x-1|
$$

At this point im stuck. What is a good approach to take from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inequality with absolute value is really two inequalities because of the piecewise definition of absolute value.

$x^2 > \frac{1}{2}|x^2-1|$

is the same as

$x^2 > \frac{1}{2}(x^2-1) >-x^2$

which you can probably solve.

Comment: Okay, I understand that I can split it into $x^2 > 1$ and $x^2 < 1$ (then I can solve the absolute value separately), but I don't understand how this implies your second equation.

Comment: Think of a simpler case. If I told you that for some number $a$ you had $|a|>5$ then that would mean two things, either $a$ itself is greater than $5$, e.g. $a=10$, or that $a$ was 'more negative' than $-5$, e.g. $a=-7$ so that $|a|=|-7|=7>5$. So if $|x^2-1|<2x^2$, then either $x^2-1 < 2x^2$ or we have that $x^2-1>-2x^2$. We can write this as a double sided inequality.

Comment: Wow, now it seems obvious! Thank you!